# How can I add incremental integer row in a text file using grep or awk command in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, awk, grep, string

I have a text file which contains 10 million+ lines. The file looks like as bellow:

```
1902400023
1902400029
1902400031
1902400032
```

I wanted to add a heading, incremental ID number and a constant SHORTCODE.
Expecting Result:

```
ID,MSISDN,SHORTCODE
1,1902400023,1
2,1902400029,1
3,1902400031,1
4,1902400032,1
```

And this will continue to till the end of file and write in another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need an `awk` code as follows

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = ","; header="ID,MSISDN,SHORTCODE" } NR == 1 { print header } 
           { $2 = $0; $1 = NR; $3 = 1; }1' file
```

In the `BEGIN` clause, we set the output field separator to the `,` operator and initialize the header string. When the file is processed, on the first line we insert the header and from the subsequent lines, we insert the lines as you've shown in the OP. `NR` is a special variable in the context of `awk` that tracks the line number which we use for your incremental counter.

Comment: yes exactly what I was looking for. Perfect output.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use awk command like below to add line numbers :

```
$ awk '{printf("%d:%s\n", NR, $0)}' millionlinetextfile > linenumberedfile
```

Comment: I just tried your command with few medication. I got the output same as I wanted except that heading line. I used the command `awk '{printf("%d,%s,1\n", NR, $0)}' file1.txt > file2.txt`